# Javaアプリ (Q&Aシステム)で、登録されている質問を編集したい

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp, servlet

Javaアプリ (Q&Aシステム)で、すでに登録済みの質問を編集したい
※最初の質問時にあらかじめ設定した編集キーと入力した編集キーが一致した場合に編集可能にする

上記の [最初の質問投稿時に設定した編集キー] の取得ができず、入力キーと比較ができません。
取得方法をご教示いただきたいです。

質問編集画面へ遷移させるコントローラ
ConfirmServlet

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import logic.ConfirmQuestionLogic;
import logic.GetAnswerLogic;
import model.Answer;
import model.Question;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ConfirmServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/ConfirmServlet")
public class ConfirmServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //文字コードエンコーディング
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        //リクエストパラメータ取得
        // int question_id = this.question_id;
        int question_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("question_id"));

        //選択された行の質問リスト取得
        ConfirmQuestionLogic ConfirmQuestionLogic = new ConfirmQuestionLogic();
        List<Question> questionList = ConfirmQuestionLogic.confirm(question_id);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("questionList", questionList);

        //選択された行の回答リスト取得
        GetAnswerLogic GetAnswerLogic = new GetAnswerLogic();
        List<Answer> answerList = GetAnswerLogic.getAnswer(question_id);
        session.setAttribute("answerList", answerList);

        //質問リスト画面へフォワード
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/QandAComfirm.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

編集画面へ遷移し、入力された値と設定されているキーを比較して更新するコントローラ
EditQuestionServlet

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import logic.EditQuestionLogic;
import logic.GetQuestionLogic;
import model.Question;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class EditServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/EditQuestionServlet")
public class EditQuestionServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int question_id;
    private String update_timestamp;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //リクエストから取得した情報を表示
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Question questionList = (Question) request.getAttribute("questionList");
        String eKey = questionList.getEdit_delete_key();

        //文字コードエンコーディング
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        //リクエストパラメータ取得
        String editKey = request.getParameter("edit_delete_key");

        if(eKey == editKey){
            //入力されたキーの質問リストを取得してスコープへ保存
            EditQuestionLogic EditQuestionLogic = new EditQuestionLogic();
            List<Question> EditQuestionList = EditQuestionLogic.findKey(editKey);
            session.setAttribute("EditQuestionList", EditQuestionList);
            //質問編集画面へフォワード
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/QandAEdit.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } else {
            //質問リスト画面へフォワード
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/QandAList.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

QandAComfirm.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
   pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date,java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="model.Question"%>
<%@ page import="model.Answer"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<Question> qlist = (List<Question>) session.getAttribute("questionList");
%>
<%
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<Answer> alist = (List<Answer>) session.getAttribute("answerList");
%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>質問確認画面</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/QandAConfirm.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header-flex">
        <div class="header-left">
          <h3>質問内容</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
          <a href="#" class="btn">戻る</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="inform">
    <div class="container">
    <form name="questionForm" action="EditQuestionServlet" method="get">
        <table border="1">
        <% for (int i=0; i<qlist.size(); i++) { %>
            <tr>
                <th>名前(ハンドルネーム)</th>
                <td><%=qlist.get(i).getHandle_name()%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>タイトル</th>
                <td><%=qlist.get(i).getTitle()%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="contents">内容</th>
                <td><%=qlist.get(i).getContents()%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>緊急度</th>
                <td><%=qlist.get(i).getUrgency()%></td>
            </tr>
       <% } %>
      </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="key">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="key-flex">
           <form name="keyForm" action="EditQuestionServlet" method="get">
             <table border="1">
                  <tr>
                    <th>編集・削除キー</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="edit_delete_key"></td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
             <div class="key-a">
             <input type="submit" name="edit" value="編集する">
             </div>
           </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="answer">
        <div class="container">
          <table border="1">
          <% for (int i=0; i<alist.size(); i++) { %>
            <tr>
              <th>回答者<input type="text" class="table-answer"><%=alist.get(i).getHandle_name()%></th>
              <th>回答日時<input type="text" class="table-answer"><%=alist.get(i).getRegist_timestamp()%></th>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <textarea name="answer" id="answer"><%=alist.get(i).getContents()%></textarea>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>回答者<input type="text" class="table-answer"><%=alist.get(i).getHandle_name()%></th>
              <th>回答日時<input type="text" class="table-answer"><%=alist.get(i).getRegist_timestamp()%></th>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <textarea name="answer" id="answer"><%=alist.get(i).getContents()%></textarea>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <% } %>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="kaitou">
        <div class="container">
          <p>回答する</p>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>名前(ハンドルネーム)</th>
              <td><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>回答</th>
              <td><textarea rows="10"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <div class="answer-btn">
            <a href="#" class="btn" id="ans">回答する</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="../WebContent/js/QandAConfirm.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

QandAEdit.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
   pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date,java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="model.Question"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<Question> elist = (List<Question>) session.getAttribute("EditQuestionList");
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content=“width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0”>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <title>質問編集画面</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/QandAEdit.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-flex">
      <div class="header-left">
        <h3>質問編集</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="header-right">
        <a href="#" class="btn">戻る</a>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="regist-form">
 <div class="container">
 <form action="/QandASystem/EditQuestionServlet" method="post">
  <table border="1">
  <% for (int i=0; i<elist.size(); i++) { %>
    <tr>
      <th>名前(ハンドルネーム)</th>
      <td><input type="text" value=<%=elist.get(i).getHandle_name()%> class="inp"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>タイトル</th>
      <td><input type="text" value=<%=elist.get(i).getTitle()%> class="inp"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="contents">内容</th>
      <td><textarea rows="16"><%=elist.get(i).getContents()%></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="urgency">
      <th>緊急度</th>
      <td>
        <label><input type="radio" name="urgency" value="1">急いでいます</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="urgency" value="2">困ってます</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="urgency" value="3">いつでも</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>編集・削除キー</th>
      <td><input type="text" value=<%=elist.get(i).getEdit_delete_key()%> class="inp"></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="編集する">
  </form>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="js/QandAEdit.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Question questionList = (Question) request.getAttribute("questionList");`から、おそらく`EditQuestionServlet`はどこかからforwardされてくるのだと思いますが、そのときに`questionList`は設定されているでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

ぱっと見での回答ですが、String型を`==`で比較してしまっているので、それが原因ではないですかね？

```java
        if(eKey == editKey){
```

↓

```java
        if(eKey != null && eKey.equals(editKey)){
```